# float div 100% height of container, all dynamic

Tags: css, html

I've been looking around and I can not find anything that solve this problem.

I have a container div, inside this one, I have few floated div, their content is generated dynamically and can vary from few words to almost a page. this basically create a line of a table (I do not want to use table layout for some reasons).

I successfully made the container expand to the bigger of the content using `overflow:hidden;`

Now I would like all my divs to adapt to the container height.

Comment: Can you give a Jsfiddle example?

Comment: here is the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9FzfJ/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set a class to all the div's inside the container ... let's say `class="contained"`

then you can add a js function to run when the document is generated that finds the max-height of all the contained div's and sets the same height to all the others.

```
  $(function() {
      var maxheight=0;
      $(".contained").each( function ()  {
          if (maxheight<$(this).height()
          maxheight=$(this).height();
      });
      $(".contained").each( function ()  {
      $(this).height(maxheight);
      }); 
}
```

Comment: that's a bit heavy no? I mean do I really need to add JS?

Comment: this is a clasic question you've provided, with unfortunately limited answers. you can do a table layout instead of divs, you can try it with js, or if your main worry is the background of the container, you can create a simple one depicting all divs at the same time, and set it as the background of the container. that way, when the container expands, the background expands and it looks like all divs expand.

Comment: I tried it out and that actually trickier, as I do not have only one line... so I should get a class for all content, then an id for the line, then run a bunch of JS functions...

Comment: Can you provide us with an example ? Maybe we'll be able to find a better solution or find a way to wrap everything up...

Comment: see there a simple one, but I actually have 50 lines. http://jsfiddle.net/9FzfJ/3/

Comment: you're a king, thanks a million and finally, JS is not too bad, I'll see if it is not too slow on my 10 column-50lines table

Comment: no problem. i hope it works for you. also ... please keep in mind that my code was using jquery ... so you might need to add the library to your code. if it helps please don't forget to mark it as resolved

Comment: after test, it works but is slow in my application, the table is displayed then adjusted, but the latency is too big (in my case), so I came back to a table-based layout.

Comment: if it's only an issue that you want the background to expand to all the divs, or borders or something, you can fake it by setting the background of the containing div ... and that way it will expand to match the height of the tallest div

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.